# What is the difference between 'it's no time', 'it's not time' and 'it's not the time'?

Tags: sentence-construction, definite-article, negation, time

Examples.

1. It's no time to stop believing. It's no time to be unsure.
2. It's not time to make a change, just relax, take it easy.
3. I don't think it's the time to start talking about the future, it's not the time to be talking contracts. We have lots of games between now and the end of the season [...]

Comment: "It's not the time" is used when you are trying to say that the time is not right to do that particular thing. For example, It's not the time to start your shenanigans. It's not the time to sleep. Your are in a class.

Comment: @lea what's the meaning of 'it's no time' and 'it's not time'?

Answer (score 2):

The usage of these three expressions overlaps. Your three examples are all valid and idiomatic. The choice depends on context and preference.

**It's not time to .....** is an expression saying that the the person/s being addressed need to be aware their focus is misdirected; under the circumstances they should be thinking of something different.

> It's not time to consider the guest list; the question is whether the wedding will take place at all.

**It's no time to.....** makes the same point but more strongly - with more emphasis.

> It's no time to be buying a new car when both your jobs could be in jeopardy.

**It's not the time....** could have been used in either or both of the examples above. Once again it makes the point that the person/s being addressed are not focusing on the real issue. They need to turn their attention elsewhere.

> It's not the time to argue about who is responsible; just clear up the mess.

Much of the time you could use any of the three expressions. Only the nuances vary from one to another. It's not a question of right and wrong but rather of context and choice.

Comment: I didn't get the difference between 'it's not time to' and 'it's not the time to'.

Comment: @user2802606 There isn't any definable difference. It's hard to think of a context in which one would be greatly preferable to the other.

Comment: Does it really matter if the person is doing (going to do) a wrong action or it is an advance warning? Or again, the difference lies not in this context?

Comment: Or does it matter was the problem why 'it's not time' or 'it's not the time' described previously or we just start speaking from this sentence?